# Google Sign-In with Firebase Auth automatically loads

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to implement google log in authentication.
Everything is done, but it doesn't work properly. When click it makes auto loading without allowing my changing, using google account. You can see it on gif underneath.
I only click first button to initialize then nothing.

fragment

```
const val REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0

@AndroidEntryPoint
class SingleModeAuthFragment @Inject constructor() :
    BaseFragment<FragmentSingleModeAuthBinding, SingleModeAuthViewModel>(
        FragmentSingleModeAuthBinding::inflate
    ) {
    override val vm: SingleModeAuthViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        layout.btnGoogleSignIn.setOnClickListener {
            val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.webclient_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
            val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), options)
            signInClient.signInIntent.also {
                startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
            val account = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data).result
            account?.let {
                googleAuthForFirebase(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun googleAuthForFirebase(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        val credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                auth.signInWithCredential(credentials).await()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    vm.navigateToViewPagerFragment()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Additionaly, I have different UI graphic, maybe you know why it cuts down in emulator?

xml of fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_list"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnGoogleSignIn"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="328dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im_google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_google" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx_google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Google Sign In"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Edit:
It works with my phone.. it is weird but the cause was just emulator IMO.

Comment: If you understand Java Java, this article [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will definitely help. If you want to learn how Jetpack Compose works, please check this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Comment: Why it doesn't work in my code. Do you have any suggestions?